# Google App Engine - Memcache - Hot key warning

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I've noticed that sometimes i get the following warning message marked with red color:

**Hot key warning (memcache compute units) /
You have significant load concentrated across only 4 values**

The first key has 56% Percentage of traffic, and the following 3 have 6-7%.
My question is: is this a major issue? What impact does it have on app performance ? (if the values in memcache disappear, they will be loaded from datastore )

I have 108 items in memcache, with a total cache size of 286KiB

Comment: Note that even 6-7% of traffic to a single key is a relatively high number. The solution is to shard hot keys data even more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a memcache best practice to distribute the load across your memcache keyspace

> **Distribute load across your memcache keyspace**. Having a single or
>   small set of memcache items represent a disproportionate amount of
>   traffic will hinder your app from scaling. This applies to both
>   operations/sec and bandwidth. The problem can often be alleviated by
>   explicit sharding of your data. For example, a frequently updated
>   counter can be split among several keys, reading them back and summing
>   only when a total is needed. Likewise, a 500K piece of data that must
>   be read on every HTTP request can be split across multiple keys and
>   read back using a single batch API call. (Even better would be to
>   cache the value in instance memory.) For dedicated memcache, the peak
>   access rate on a single key should be 1-2 orders of magnitude less
>   than the per-GB rating.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/memcache

Comment: Does concentrated load refers to write, read or both (ie. any of these) ?

Comment: The concentration is related to the load handled by the servers. If you have multipled keys, the load is balanced through different connections/servers so your application can scale more fast because you are using different servers. IF you use a small set of items, you are increasing the traffic to the same asset.